# Split a list into list of lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a list of predicates:

```
[patient(204,4,2),patient(203,3,2),patient(303,7,3),patient(302,6,3),patient(404,12,4),patient(403,11,4),patient(504,16,5),patient(503,15,5)]
```

I want to have a list of lists depending on the 3rd argument of each predicate:

```
[ [patient(204,4,2),patient(203,3,2)] , [patient(303,7,3),patient(302,6,3)] , [patient(404,12,4),patient(403,11,4)] , [patient(504,16,5),patient(503,15,5)] ]
```

Comment: Stop calling it a list of "predicates". Those are triples, or maybe compound terms with arity three.

Comment: Also discussed in https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/sorting-predicates-in-prolog/5618

Answer (score 1):

You can [`group_by/4`](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=group_by/4) which [works in mysterious ways](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/group-by-4-examples/2678) and will get you a single sublist at a time. E.g. assuming your list is `Patients`:

```
group_by(C, patient(A,B), member(patient(A,B,C), Patients), Group)
```

Then

```
Group = [patient(204,4), patient(203,3)]
```

I can't get "C" into the group, which is annoying because we'll have to put it back in later. Use [`findall/3`](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) to get all the groups:

```
findall(C-Group,
    group_by(C, patient(A,B), member(patient(A,B,C), _Patients), Group),
AllGroups)
```

That makes something of this shape, with the grouping value on the front of the sublists:

```
AllGroups = [
  2-[patient(204,4), patient(203,3)],
  3-[patient(303,7), patient(302,6)],
  4-[patient(404,12), patient(403,11)],
  5-[patient(504,16), patient(503,15)]
]
```

And then some post-processing to put C back in:

```
restoreC([], []).
restoreC([C-Group|CBs], [L|Ls]) :-
    maplist({C}/[P1,P2]>>(P1=patient(A,B),P2=patient(A,B,C)), Group, L),
    restoreC(CBs, Ls).
```

Tag `,restoreC(AllGroups, Result)` onto the end for:

```
Result = [
  [patient(204,4,2), patient(203,3,2)],
  [patient(303,7,3), patient(302,6,3)],
  [patient(404,12,4), patient(403,11,4)],
  [patient(504,16,5), patient(503,15,5)]
]
```

Comment: indeed group_by/4 has a weird semantic... maybe distinct/2 is easier to use.

Comment: There is no mystery in how group_by/4 works. Unless of course you try to decipher the intent of whoever bothers to write those (imho useless and confusing) examples that you have linked. The docs also immediately suggest you don't need it and could use bagof/3 instead: maybe the more familiar interface helps with the confusion?

Comment: @TA_intern the mystery is why putting C into the template so: `group_by(C, patient(A,B,C), member(patient(A,B,C), Patients), Group)` means it doesn't so any grouping it just returns everything. bagof/3 has the same mystery behaviour. The docs for group_by say it's there to be like a SQL query, so imagine you're doing a traditional SQL query "sales grouped by country" but ... you can't have the country in the results. Who would want it to work like that? Of course you want the grouping element in the result set it's a more important bit of the result set.

Comment: @TA_intern Another mystery is the docs for bagof/groupby describe an `A^functor(A,B)` syntax to not bind variable A in the goal, but that seems no different from `functor(_,B)` only longer and less clear.

Comment: bagof/3 (and its cousing setof/3) are indeed confusing, maybe the right way to say it was that you need to fight your own way through it and examples don't exactly help with this. This is a recurring theme so there must be a problem with the interface and the mental model it imposes. I usually end up making some experiments until I figure out what is the right way to get what I want and how it is different from the other ways. The two examples in your last comment where you say "seems no different" are certainly different, but this is too much for a comment

Answer (score 0):

Copying my answer from https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/sorting-predicates-in-prolog/5618/19 here:

```
test_sort_group(Group) :-
    Patients = [patient(204,4,2),patient(203,3,2),patient(304,8,3),patient(303,7,3),patient(404,12,4),patient(403,11,4),patient(504,16,5),patient(503,15,5),patient(1,1,1),patient(506,6,5)],
    group_list_by_arg(3, Patients, Group).


group_list_by_arg(Arg, Lst, Group) :-
    % Keeping duplicates
    sort(Arg, @=<, Lst, [H|T]),
    group_list_by_arg_main_(T, Arg, H, Group).

group_list_by_arg_main_(T, Arg, H, Group) :-
    arg(Arg, H, ArgVal),
    Upto = [H|Upto0],
    group_list_by_arg_loop_(T, Arg, ArgVal, Upto0, Rem),
    group_list_by_arg_rem_(Rem, Arg, Upto, Group).

% Reached end of groups
group_list_by_arg_rem_([], _, G, G).
group_list_by_arg_rem_([_|_], _, G, G).
group_list_by_arg_rem_([H|T], Arg, _Upto, Group) :-
    % Assemble next group
    group_list_by_arg_main_(T, Arg, H, Group).

% Reached end of sorted list
group_list_by_arg_loop_([], _, _, [], []).
group_list_by_arg_loop_([H|T], Arg, ArgVal, Group, Rem) :-
    arg(Arg, H, ArgVal), !,
    % Add element to current group
    Group = [H|Group0],
    group_list_by_arg_loop_(T, Arg, ArgVal, Group0, Rem).
% Finished this group, but there may be other elements
group_list_by_arg_loop_([H|T], _Arg, _ArgVal, [], [H|T]).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(bagof(G, test_sort_group(G), Gs)).
% 49 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (94% CPU, 599807 Lips)
Gs = [[patient(1,1,1)],[patient(204,4,2),patient(203,3,2)],[patient(304,8,3),patient(303,7,3)],[patient(404,12,4),patient(403,11,4)],[patient(504,16,5),patient(503,15,5),patient(506,6,5)]].
```